# Very long string attributes stall Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have stored in Firebase images in base64 format (strings length around 100k~150k chars) and it worked well for days. Yesterday and today stopped working even though the data stored are the same. I have problems also using the Firebase data view (it stalls 90% of the times I do a refresh). Someone had the same issue?

Comment: I tried to export the data in json from the Firebase data view but hangs!

Comment: Can you provide an example to reproduce this problem?

Comment: I used simple on/one calls but I guess the problem was that I encoded images in base64 (very long strings).

Comment: Base64 is the recommended approach actually. That shouldn't be a problem at all. Can you please provide an example where this isn't working properly?

Comment: Firebase guys told me that they had an overload traffic from one big client and it was the reason for the temporary malfunction. Now works well.